# Sort Dictionary by values in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there are analog of - (NSArray *)keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator in swift?

How to do this without casting to NSDictionary?

I tried this, but it seems to be not a good solution.

```
var values = Array(dict.values)
values.sort({
    $0 > $1
    })

for number in values {
    for (key, value) in dict {
        if value == number {
            println(key + " : \(value)");
            dict.removeValueForKey(key);
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]
dict.sortedKeysByValues(>) // fanta (12), cola(10), sprite(8)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31528848/2303865

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
let dict = ["a":1, "c":3, "b":2]

extension Dictionary {
    func sortedKeys(isOrderedBefore:(Key,Key) -> Bool) -> [Key] {
        return Array(self.keys).sort(isOrderedBefore)
    }

    // Slower because of a lot of lookups, but probably takes less memory (this is equivalent to Pascals answer in an generic extension)
    func sortedKeysByValue(isOrderedBefore:(Value, Value) -> Bool) -> [Key] {
        return sortedKeys {
            isOrderedBefore(self[$0]!, self[$1]!)
        }
    }

    // Faster because of no lookups, may take more memory because of duplicating contents
    func keysSortedByValue(isOrderedBefore:(Value, Value) -> Bool) -> [Key] {
        return Array(self)
            .sort() {
                let (_, lv) = $0
                let (_, rv) = $1
                return isOrderedBefore(lv, rv)
            }
            .map {
                let (k, _) = $0
                return k
            }
    }
}

dict.keysSortedByValue(<)
dict.keysSortedByValue(>)
```

Updated:

Updated to the new array syntax and sort semantics from beta 3.  Note that I'm using `sort` and not `sorted` to minimize array copying.  The code could be made more compact, by looking at the earlier version and replacing `sort` with `sorted` and fixing the `KeyType[]` to be `[KeyType]`

Updated to Swift 2.2:

Changed types from `KeyType` to `Key` and `ValueType` to `Value`.  Used new `sort` builtin to `Array` instead of `sort(Array)`  Note performance of all of these could be slightly improved by using `sortInPlace` instead of `sort`

Comment: Very interesting, but not what I need. It's only sorted keys. But I need keys sorted by values. 
Smth like 

    dict.sortedKeysByValues(>)  --> b, c, a; 
    dict.sortedKeysByValues(<)  --> a, c, b;

Comment: Sorry, misread what you were doing as just wanting the keys sorted.

Comment: @NikeAlive edited to do what you want, thanks for the problem :)

Comment: writing with Swift suppose to be simpler than objective-c? without casting to NSDictionary this is not easiest way to sort... or i am missing something?

Comment: @mohacs you're missing something.  Sorting the keys of a dictionary by value is about the same level of complexity in Objective-C.  Note that my answer presents two completely different methods of doing the same thing, the first of which is pretty much identical to what it would be in Objective-C.

Comment: probably i am, because with Obj-c i am sorting the keys of a dictionary by value with this NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"KeyName" ascending:NO]; then one more line. can you explain what it the difference? thanks.

Comment: @mohacs I think you're confusing sorting an array of dictionaries by the value associated with a particular key (what you seem to be referring to) and sorting the keys of a dictionary by value in the dictionary which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @David definitely confusion, you are right. now i understand thank you.

Comment: This doesn't compile with Xcode Beta 3.  `KeyType[]` is now `[KeyType]` but that's only a warning, the compile error is on the `return sort(Array(...`.  Compiler says `'NSArray' is not a subtype of 'inout C'` whatever that means!?!

Comment: I've got it compiling in Xcode Beta3 now but I can't test it due to unrelated issues, the [updated code is here](https://github.com/progrmr/State_Hunt_swift/blob/master/State_Hunt/NSDictionary%2BSort.swift#L12)

Comment: They've changed the semantics of `sort` to take an inout array that is sorted in place.  The old functionality is now available as `sorted`  I'll update the answers tomorrow when I'm at a computer to validate everything.

Comment: The above code gives me in Xcode 6 Beta5 the errors: "Use of undeclared type 'KeyType'" and if I change all KeyType/ValueType by Int the compiler says: "'Key' is not a subtype of 'Int'" and "'Key' is not identical to 'Int'" in the first "func SortedKeys...". Any idea or fix for Xcode6 Beta5?

Comment: As of Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3.1 all that needs to be changed in order to compile in this extension is to change throughout `KeyType` to `Key` and `ValueType` to `Value`

Comment: Updated the answer to Swift 2.2 syntax and functions.

Answer (score 98):

Just one line code to sort dictionary by Values in Swift 4, 4.2 and Swift 5:

```
let sortedByValueDictionary = myDictionary.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
```

Comment: It works for me in Swift 4.1 using Dictionary<String, Int>

Comment: N.B. returns an array of tuples `(key, value)`, so you'll need to read the contents like this if you want the object: `array[x].1`

Comment: I am fairly new to Swift, and think that this answer could be made stronger by briefly explaining the syntax `{ $0.1 < $1.1 }`

Comment: Thanks, @Ash for the note! In my case, I needed to get the key for each tuple, by doing: `array[x].key`

Comment: On another note, in my case I needed to sort by values which are numbers in strings, so I ended up with: `let sortedByValueDictionary = myDictionary.sorted {$0.value.localizedStandardCompare($1.value) == .orderedAscending}` (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870210)

Comment: @JohnHarrington: so as a try for an explanation: the `$0` and `$1` are the "two pseudo entries" for defining the compare function (which is then applied by the `sorted` function on all entries of the dictionary). Since we want to compare by value, we have to use the second element (0 is the key, 1 is the value), hence the `.1`. (So you can also write `{ $0.value < $1.value }`.)

Answer (score 24):

You could use something like this perhaps:

```
var dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]

var myArr = Array(dict.keys)
var sortedKeys = sort(myArr) {
    var obj1 = dict[$0] // get ob associated w/ key 1
    var obj2 = dict[$1] // get ob associated w/ key 2
    return obj1 > obj2
}

myArr // ["fanta", "cola", "sprite"]
```

Comment: The above gives in Xcode6 Beta5 the following error: "Passing value of type 'Array<String>' to an inout parameter requires explicit '&'". However if I fix this to "var sortedKeys = sort(&myArr)" I get the warning: "Variable 'sortedKeys' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected". Fixing this to "var sortedKeys: () = sort(&myArr)" gives the specified result for myArr. Any idea on how do we sort on keys (if possible)? See also my comment to @David's code in the accepted answer.

Comment: `sort(myArr)`, sort does not exist in Swift 4 anymore.

Comment: Use myArr.sorted() for swift 4

Answer (score 22):

This should give you the sorted keys based on value, and is a little more cleaner:

```
var sortedKeys = Array(dict.keys).sorted(by: { dict[$0]! < dict[$1]! })
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your answer, code only answers are not considered good.

Answer (score 12):

#### OneLiner :

```
let dict = ["b": 2, "a": 1, "c": 3]
(Array(dict).sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }).forEach { (k,v) in print("\(k):\(v)") }
//Output: a:1, b:2, c:3
```

Swap out the `.forEach` with `.map` -> Functional programming

#### Syntactical sugar :

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Comparable {
    var sortedByValue: [(Key, Value)] { return Array(self).sorted { $0.1 < $1.1} }
}
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable {
    var sortedByKey: [(Key, Value)] { return Array(self).sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 } }
}
["b": 2, "a": 1, "c": 3].sortedByKey // a:1, b:2, c:3
["b": 2, "a": 1, "c": 3].sortedByValue // a:1, b:2, c:3
```

Comment: the emojis are annoying.

Comment: @vikingosegundo OK ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andy Thx for your edit, however some important context was deleted. And I had to re-edit. Whats stackoverflow rules on emojies anyway?

Comment: dict is not defined in the second part of you answer. It should be changed to self I believe

Comment: @Titouan de Bailleul Thanks. Updated.

Comment: let dict = ["b":"2","a":"1","c":"3"].sortedByKey
        print("dict ::: \(dict)")
        dict ::: [("a", "1"), ("b", "2"), ("c", "3")], Actually the result has to be dict ::: ["a":"1", "b": "2", "c": "3"]

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the easiest way to sort Swift dictionary by value.

```
let dict = ["apple":1, "cake":3, "banana":2]

let byValue = {
    (elem1:(key: String, val: Int), elem2:(key: String, val: Int))->Bool in
    if elem1.val < elem2.val {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
let sortedDict = dict.sort(byValue)
```

Comment: perfect thank you :) Works with swift5 (sort is now sorted(by: byValue)

Comment: But the returned value is keyvalue pairs not dictionary :(

Comment: @MuraliDharanV I may be inaccurate because I haven't been developing iOS these days, but in most programming languages, key-value pairs are called dictionaries.

Answer (score 8):

Sorting your keys by the dictionary's value is actually simpler than it appears at first:

```
let yourDict = ["One": "X", "Two": "B", "Three": "Z", "Four": "A"]
let sortedKeys = yourDict.keys.sort({ (firstKey, secondKey) -> Bool in
    return yourDict[firstKey] < yourDict[secondKey]
})
```

And that's it! There's really nothing more to it. I have yet to find a quicker method, other than the same approach in form of a simple one-liner:

```
let yourDict = ["One": "X", "Two": "B", "Three": "Z", "Four": "A"]
let sortedKeys = yourDict.keys.sort { yourDict[$0] < yourDict[$1] }
```

Answer (score 8):

Lots of answers, here's a one-liner. I like it because it makes full use of native Swift iterative functions and doesn't use variables. This should help the optimiser do its magic.

```
return dictionary.keys.sort({ $0 < $1 }).flatMap({ dictionary[$0] })
```

Note the use of flatMap, because subscripting a dictionary returns an optional value. In practice this should never return nil since we get the key from the dictionary itself. `flatMap` is there only to ensure that the result is not an array of optionals. If your array's associated value should BE an optional you can use `map` instead.

Answer (score 6):

### Sorting a dictionary by key or value

Using **Swift 5.2** internal handling of "sorted":

```
var unsortedDict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]

// sorting by value
let sortedDictByValue = unsortedDict.sorted{ $0.value > $1.value } // from lowest to highest using ">"
print("sorted dict: \(sortedDictByValue)")
// result: "sorted dict: [(key: "fanta", value: 12), (key: "cola", value: 10), (key: "sprite", value: 8)]\n"

// highest value
print(sortedDictByValue.first!.key)  // result: fanta
print(sortedDictByValue.first!.value)  // result: 12
// lowest value
print(sortedDictByValue.last!.key)  // result: sprite
print(sortedDictByValue.last!.value)  // result: 8
// by index
print(sortedDictByValue[1].key)  // result: cola
print(sortedDictByValue[1].value)  // result: 10

// sorting by key
let sortedDictByKey = unsortedDict.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key } // in alphabetical order use "<"
// alternative:
// let sortedDictByKey = unsortedDict.sorted{ $0 < $1 }  // without ".key"
print("sorted dict: \(sortedDictByKey)")
// result: "sorted dict: [(key: "cola", value: 10), (key: "fanta", value: 12), (key: "sprite", value: 8)]\n"

// highest value
print(sortedDictByKey.first!.key)  // result: cola
print(sortedDictByKey.first!.value)  // result: 10
// lowest value
print(sortedDictByKey.last!.key)  // result: sprite
print(sortedDictByKey.last!.value)  // result: 8
// by index
print(sortedDictByKey[1].key)  // result: fanta
print(sortedDictByKey[1].value)  // result: 12
```

Comment: of course!, can't see why this is not the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

The following might be useful if you want the output to be an array of key value pairs in the form of a tuple, sorted by value.

```
var dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]
let sortedArrByValue = dict.sorted{$0.1 > $1.1}
print(sortedArrByValue) // output [(key: "fanta", value: 12), (key: "cola", value: 10), (key: "sprite", value: 8)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Swift 3.0 `Dictionary` has `sorted(by:)` function which returns an array of tuples (`[(Key, Value)]`).

```
let sorted = values.sorted(by: { (keyVal1, keyVal2) -> Bool in
    keyVal1.value > keyVal2.value
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Just cast it to NSDictionary and then call the method. Anywhere you use `@selector` in ObjC you can just use a String in Swift. So it would look like this:

```
var dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]
let sortedKeys = (dict as NSDictionary).keysSortedByValueUsingSelector("compare:")
```

or

```
let sortedKeys2 = (dict as NSDictionary).keysSortedByValueUsingComparator 
                  { 
                       ($0 as NSNumber).compare($1 as NSNumber) 
                  }
```

Comment: Cast is too simple =) I thought in swift I can do most things easier than in objc

Comment: @NikeAlive haha! Maybe by the time we get to swift 2.0…

Comment: This is the best answer that is actually doing what the question asked. Sort a dictionary by "VALUE", not key.

Answer (score 4):

As of Swift 3, to sort your keys based on values, the below looks promising:

```
var keys = Array(dict.keys)        
keys.sortInPlace { (o1, o2) -> Bool in
    return dict[o1]! as! Int > dict[o2]! as! Int
}
```

Comment: I had to replace `dict.keys` with `dict.allKeys` for use with my NSMutableArray in Xcode 8 beta 1.

Answer (score 3):

`var dict = ["cola" : 10, "fanta" : 12, "sprite" : 8]`

```
let arr = dic.sort{ (d1,d2)-> Bool in
if d1.value > d2.value {
    retrn true
}

}.map { (key,value) -> Int in
return value
}
```

Take look a clean implementation way.
print("arr is :(arr)")

Answer (score 2):

The following way in Swift 3 sorted my dictionary by value in the ascending order:

```
for (k,v) in (Array(dict).sorted {$0.1 < $1.1}) {
    print("\(k):\(v)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 3:

Using a few resources I put this beautifully short code together.

```
dictionary.keys.sorted{dictionary[$0]! < dictionary[$1]!}
```

This returns an array of the dictionary keys sorted by their values. It works perfectly & doesn't throw errors when the dictionary is empty. Try this code in a playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let dictionary = ["four": 4, "one": 1, "seven": 7, "two": 2, "three": 3]

let sortedDictionary = dictionary.keys.sorted{dictionary[$0]! < dictionary[$1]!}

print(sortedDictionary)
// ["one", "two", "three", "four", "seven"]


let emptyDictionary = [String: Int]()

let emptyDictionarySorted = emptyDictionary.keys.sorted{emptyDictionary[$0]! < emptyDictionary[$1]!}

print(emptyDictionarySorted)
// []
```

If you'd like some help on why the heck the code uses $0, $1 and doesn't even have parentheses after the "sorted" method, check out this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785745/7107094

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it - sorting in this case by a key called position.  Try this in a playground:

```swift
var result: [[String: AnyObject]] = []
result.append(["name" : "Ted", "position": 1])
result.append(["name" : "Bill", "position": 0])
result


result = sorted(result, positionSort)

func positionSort(dict1: [String: AnyObject], dict2: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    let position1 = dict1["position"] as? Int ?? 0
    let position2 = dict2["position"] as? Int ?? 0
    return position1 < position2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the dictionary with a dictionary as the value (Nested dictionary)

```
   var students: [String: [String: Any?]] = ["16CSB40" : ["Name": "Sunitha", "StudentId": "16CSB40", "Total": 90], "16CSB41" : ["Name": "Vijay", "StudentId": "16CSB40", "Total": 80], "16CSB42" : ["Name": "Tony", "StudentId": "16CSB42", "Total": 95]] // Sort this dictionary with total value

    let sorted = students.sorted { (($0.1["Total"] as? Int) ?? 0) < (($1.1["Total"] as? Int) ?? 0) }

    print(sorted) //Sorted result
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, and then just loop through the dictionary again using the output keys.

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Comparable {
  func sortedKeysByValue() -> [Key] {
    keys.sorted { return self[$0]! < self[$1]! }
  }
}
```

...or this if you hate force unwrapping :)

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Comparable {
  func sortedKeysByValue() -> [Key] {
    keys.sorted { (key1, key2) -> Bool in
      guard let val1 = self[key1] else { return true }
      guard let val2 = self[key2] else { return true }
      return val1 < val2
    }
  }
}
```