# Swift sort dictionary for table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I will use for populating a table:

```
["struvite":716,"calcium_oxalate":388,"urate":217,"calcium_phosphate":30,"silica":21,"compound":41]
```

I understand that dictionaries are, by definition, not sorted, and that tableView works on Arrays, not dictionaries.

So my problem is two fold.  I need to sort this data by value and place it in an array so I can easily get it into a table.  I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639993/swift-sort-dictionary-by-value) for sorting but it seems out of date for Swift 2.

The result I'm looking for would be something like this:

---

struvite (716)

calcium_oxalate (388)

urate (217)

compound (41)

calcium_phosphate (30)

silica (21)

---

Where each line is an element of the array and they appear in descending order by what was once their value in the dictionary.  Once it's in an array, I can get it into a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let dict = ["struvite": 716, "calcium_oxalate": 388, "urate": 217, "calcium_phosphate": 30, "silica": 21, "compound": 41]
let test = dict.sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }
```

Result is:

```
[("struvite", 716), ("calcium_oxalate", 388), ("urate", 217), ("compound", 41), ("calcium_phosphate", 30), ("silica", 21)]
```

You can access this and assign it to your cells like this:

```
let name = test[indexPath.row].0
let number = test[indexPath.row].1
```

Comment: Perfect.  My error was in thinking that because dictionaries aren't sorted, I wouldn't be able to call sort on a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The easy to reay way to do this in swift would be something along these lines, supposed that `dictionary : [String:Int]`.

```
struct Compound : Equatable, Comparable {
   let name : String
   let value : Int
}
func ==(x : Compound, y : Compound) -> Bool {
   return x.value == y.value
}
func <(x : Compound, y : Compound) -> Bool {
   return x.value < y.value
}

var compounds = [Compound]()
for (key, value) in dictionary {
   compounds.append(Compound(name: key, value: value)
}
let sorted = compounds.sort(>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your example:

```
let dict = ["struvite":716,"calcium_oxalate":388,"urate":217,"calcium_phosphate":30,"silica":21,"compound":41]
```

This part will sort from the biggest and actually transform dictionary to array of tupples:

```
let sortedTupples = dict.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return lhs.1 > rhs.1
}
```

This will result in exact form that you want, it's an array of strings:

```
let arrayOfStringsFromTupples = sortedTupples.map { "\($0.0) (\($0.1))" }
```

Map function maps each tupple entry into defined in clojure type, and here we've just created on string object, but actually it could be any different object.

**In short**

```
let dict = ["struvite":716,"calcium_oxalate":388,"urate":217,"calcium_phosphate":30,"silica":21,"compound":41]
let allInOne = dict.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return lhs.1 > rhs.1
}.map { "\($0.0) (\($0.1))" }
```