# Sort Dictionary by Key Value

Tags: swift, sorting

```
let dict: [String:Int] = ["apple":5, "pear":9, "grape":1]
```

How do you sort the dictionary based on the `Int` value so that the output is:

```
sortedDict = ["pear":9, "apple":5, "grape":1]
```

#### Current Attempt (doesn't sort correctly):

```
let sortedDict = sorted(dict) { $0.1 > $1.1 }
```

Comment: Dictionary don't have sort order by design. They are key value container.

Comment: So I need to convert to an array, sort, then recreate the dictionary?

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090016/sort-dictionary-by-values-in-swift

Comment: I can't think of a use case where you'd need the dictionary to be sorted. What you usually want to do is obtain the keys as a list, order the list, then iterate over that ordered list to access the values.

Comment: @Emma, how would the recreated dictionary be able to have a sort order?

Comment: @palpatim i'm using the dictionary to store a string with an associated vote count. I would like to sort the values by highest > lowest votes (`Int` value in the dictionary).

Comment: Emma In other words, you wish the values of the dictionary to be sorted, not the dictionary itself. It's a subtle wording change, but a profoundly different way of thinking about the problem. @lamar's reference above will give you some pointers in sorting a dictionary by value. It will be up to you to then construct a list (e.g., an Array) of the key-value pairs in the order you want.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to sort your dictionary values, not your keys. You can create an array of tuples from your dictionary sorting it by its values as follow:

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4** or **Xcode 8 • Swift 3**

```
let fruitsDict = ["apple": 5, "pear": 9, "grape": 1]
let fruitsTupleArray = fruitsDict.sorted{ $0.value > $1.value }

fruitsTupleArray // [(.0 "pear", .1 9), (.0 "apple", .1 5), (.0 "grape", .1 1)]

for (fruit,votes) in fruitsTupleArray {
    print(fruit,votes)
}

fruitsTupleArray.first?.key   // "pear"
fruitsTupleArray.first?.value   // 9
```

---

To sort your dictionary using your keys

```
let fruitsTupleArray = fruitsDict.sorted{ $0.key > $1.key }
fruitsTupleArray  // [(key "pear", value 9), (key "grape", value 1), (key "apple", value 5)]
```

To sort your dictionary using its keys and localized comparison:

```
let fruitsTupleArray = fruitsDict.sorted { $0.key.localizedCompare($1.key) == .orderedAscending  }
```

---

**edit/update**:

We can also extend `Sequence` protocol and implement a custom sort that takes a predicate and sort using a keypath property as long as it conforms to `Comparable`:

```
extension Sequence {
    func sorted<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T, by areInIncreasingOrder: ((T,T)-> Bool) = (<)) -> [Element] {
        sorted(by: { areInIncreasingOrder(predicate($0), predicate($1)) })
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let sortedFruitsAscending = fruitsDict.sorted(\.value)
print(sortedFruitsAscending)

let sortedFruitsDescending = fruitsDict.sorted(\.value, by: >)
print(sortedFruitsDescending)
```

---

This will print

> [(key: "grape", value: 1), (key: "apple", value: 5), (key: "pear", value: 9)]
> [(key: "pear", value: 9), (key: "apple", value: 5), (key: "grape", value: 1)]

---

**edit/update**:

For **Xcode 13 or later** you can use a new generic structure called [`KeyPathComparator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/keypathcomparator):

```
let fruitsTupleArray = fruitsDict.sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\.value, order: .reverse))
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Extremely simple, readable and independent. Works with Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries can't be sorted. Generally, when I need things sorted from a dictionary, I will make a separate array of my dictionary keys.

In your case, make an array of the keys, sort them by comparing their values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using the below implementation

`let sortedDictionary = unsortedDictionary.sorted{$0.key > $1.key}`

Answer (score 0):

use KeyValuePairs instead of Dictionary

"The order of key-value pairs in a dictionary is stable between mutations but is otherwise unpredictable. If you need an ordered collection of key-value pairs and don’t need the fast key lookup that Dictionary provides, see the KeyValuePairs type for an alternative." - [Swift Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary)

Comment: This has many limitations considering that you can't add any new value for an existing collection.