# Dictionary print key and value in Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary

Hello I tried a print dictionary items at Xcode9. Like this:

```
var items = ["Bear":"0", "Glass":"1", "Car":"2"]

for (key,value) in items{

print("\(key) : \(value)")

}
```

output:

```
Glass : 1
Bear : 0
Car : 2
```

Why output not like this: Bear: 0, Glass:1, Car:2 
I dont understand this output reason.

Comment: dictionary types are not sorted.

Comment: You can sort your dictionary instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31528848/3687801).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Dictionary :**

A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering.

Each value is associated with a unique key, which acts as an identifier for that value within the dictionary. Unlike items in an array, items in a dictionary **do not have a specified order**.

**Array -** An array stores values of the same type in **an ordered list**.

**Sets -** A set stores distinct values of the same type in a collection with **no defined ordering**.

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`Dictionary` in Swift is implemented as hash map. There is no guarantee that items in `Dictionary` will have the same order you added them.

The only container that retains the order of items is `Array`. You can use it to store tuples, like so:

```
var items : [(key: String, value: String)] = [(key: "Bear", value: "0"),(key: "Glass", value: "1"), (key: "Car", value: "2")]
```

Your iteration will work as expected, but you will lose `Dictionary's` ability to lookup items by subscript

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Your question is your example @Mayday

Comment: @BhavinRamani yes right:) example for ordered items. How can I order?

Answer (score 1):

- `Arrays` are ordered collections of values.
- `Sets` are unordered collections of unique values.
- `Dictionaries` are unordered
  collections of key-value associations.

So, You can not expect the same order, when you are iterating the values from Dictionary.

[Reference to Collection Type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary` collection isn't ordered, that is *it simply doesn't guarantee to be ordered*. But `Array` is. `Dictionary` adds values in discrete orders whereas `Array` adds values in continuous order.

You simply can't have an `Array` like this:

```
["a", "b", ... , "d", ... , ... , "g"]    //Discrete index aren't allowed. You just can't skip any index in between.
```

Instead you have to have the above array like this:

```
["a", "b", "d", "g"]
```

To be able to get rid of this behavior, `Dictionary` *(where you don't have to maintain previous indexes to have values)* was introduced. So you can insert values as you like. It won't bother you for maintaining any index.