# Finding 25 most occurring string

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I am iterating over some strings I get from my server. I need to know which 25 of the strings occur the most. I was wondering what the most efficient / fastest way of doing that can me. I could get anywhere from 1000 to 10000 strings. I was thinking of an approach where I make a map of string to occurrence. Then make a list of the occurrences. Sort that list. Then iterate over the `(key,value)`s in the map and find the ones corresponding to those highest numbers. Sounds a bit convoluted so thought I would ask to see if anyone has a better approach. Everything I found online is pretty similar to what I was thinking.

Comment: you can use an NSCountedSet to keep the tally. You will still need to iterate the set to build the list of top 25

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use case for Cocoa's `CountedSet` ([Apple Dev Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/)).

Example provided by [hackingwithswift.com](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-count-objects-in-a-set-using-nscountedset)

```
let set = NSCountedSet()
set.addObject("Bob")
set.addObject("Charlotte")
...
set.addObject("Bob")

print(set.countForObject("Bob")) // prints 2
```

Now you are able to sort your dict with build in `sort()`methods. For example please have a look at this related [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090016/sort-dictionary-by-values-in-swift).

**Update**

A possible method to sort is:

`set.sort { return set.countForObject($0) < set.countForObject($1) }`

Comment: Hi how can I sort it with the built in methods? I can't seem to call `set.sort()`

Comment: `NSCountedSet` does not have a method `-sort:`

Comment: I used my Playground to evaluated the posted source. Sorry if I made a mistake or I waved to a false friend.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common pattern. In AWK, the text processing language, it was so common that the implementation was absurdly simple: `stringCount[newString]++`.

In Swift, we need to be a bit more explicit - Playground code using pure Swift:

```
var stringCount: [String: Int] = [:] // i.e. a Dictionary keyed by the strings, whose value is the occurrence count

func addString(newString: String) {
    if let oldCount = stringCount[newString] { // We have seen this string before
        stringCount[newString] = oldCount + 1
    } else { // It's the first time we've seen this one
        stringCount[newString] = 1
    }
}

addString("Grimxn")
addString("TurtleFan")
addString("Grimxn")
addString("Grimxn")
addString("TurtleFan")
addString("Stack Overflow")

stringCount // ["Grimxn": 3, "TurtleFan": 2, "Stack Overflow": 1]
```

Or, as @Paulw11 points out, you could use Cocoa's `NSCountedSet`:

```
var stringCount2 = NSCountedSet()

stringCount2.addObject("Grimxn")
stringCount2.addObject("TurtleFan")
stringCount2.addObject("Grimxn")
stringCount2.addObject("Grimxn")
stringCount2.addObject("TurtleFan")
stringCount2.addObject("Stack Overflow")

let counts = stringCount2.map( { return ($0, stringCount2.countForObject($0)) } )
counts // [(.0 "TurtleFan", .1 2), (.0 "Stack Overflow", .1 1), (.0 "Grimxn", .1 3)]
```

Comment: You have built a counted set using a dictionary

Comment: Yes! That's how we did it back before Cocoa. :)