# Sorting dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary, swift3, xcode8

Trying to sort an NSMutableDictionary in Swift 3, code from Swift 2 doesn't work for me anymore (various errors).

I am trying to use the following code to sort my dictionary by its values, which are floats:

```
var sortedDict = unsortedDict.allValues.sorted({ $0 < $1 }).flatMap({ floatedlotterydictionary[$0] })
```

Essentially, I want this unsorted dictionary...

```
{
a = "1.7";
b = "0.08";
c = "1.4";
}
```

...to turn into this sorted dictionary...

```
{
b = "0.08";
c = "1.4";
a = "1.7";
}
```

But using that line of code from above returns the error "argument type anyobject does not conform with type NSCopying" for the `$0 < $1` part. So how can I sort a dictionary by its values in Swift 3?

(Note: That line of code came in part from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37816131/5700898).)

I am using **Swift 3** in **Xcode 8 beta 1**.

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition. It is impossible to get your requested result as a dictionary. And don't use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift. It is not related to the Swift `Dictionary` at all.

Comment: And yes, I understand a dictionary is unordered...but I want it ordered ;). And though it is somewhat unrelated, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. The collection methods available on a normal dictionary are still available, however the type of objects is not enforced, which adds an inherit unsafely.

In the [docs](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/Dictionary/#comment-func-sorted_) the `sorted` takes a closure which lets us access the key and value at the same time and consider it as one element and hence sort your dictionary.

```
let k: NSMutableDictionary = ["a" : 1.7, "b" : 0.08, "c" : 1.4]
print(k.sorted(isOrderedBefore: { (a, b) in (a.value as! Double) < (b.value as! Double) }))
```

The casting is required, as the type of `a.value` and `b.value` is `AnyObject`. This works on my computer, running Xcode Version 8.0 beta (8S128d).

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary` does **not** bridge to Swift `Dictionary`

Comment: I'm at a laptop now - Thanks.

Comment: The result is an array of tuples, not a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed! It works perfectly.

Comment: @vadian What are you talking about that NSMutableDictionary doesn't bridge to Dictionary? Here's some code that bridges it: `var nsmutabledictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dictionary)`

Comment: @JohnRamos The other way round. Try `let md = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["a" : 1, "b" : 2])` `md as [String: Int]` ...

Comment: @vadian Thank you, but I already have Mrwerdo's great answer.

Comment: This seems to be outdated could that be try?
It seems like the swift 3 syntax is a little different now a days since I can't seem to get this working

Comment: The method call for `sorted(isOrderedBefore:)` has changed to `sorted(by:)` - Xcode should correct this. I'm unsure what the latest syntax is on the development branch, though I am using the latest version of Xcode (and the Swift that accompanies it). What's your specific issue?

Answer (score 4):

There's also this way:

```
let k = ["a" : 1.7, "b" : 0.08, "c" : 1.4]

print(k.flatMap({$0}).sort { $0.0.1 < $0.1.1 })
```