# Dictionary returns consecutive/shuffled values when iterating in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have following dictionary

```
var data : [String: String] = ["DEV" : "DEV", "QUA" : "QUA" , "SIT" : "SIT", "UAT" : "UAT", "PROD" : "PROD"]
```

I Iterate it using for loop and get the following values

```
SIT
PROD
DEV
UAT
QUA
```

ie consecutive values

i have the following code to iterate it

```
for (key, value ) in data.enumerate()
{
    print(value)
}
```

I want to get these values in same format of declaration.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by default.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24090641/988169)

Answer (score 0):

Swift `Dictionary` type is unordered type. On every `for in` loop you can receive different ordered result (in theory). You should choose other data structure if you wish to keep order, `Array<(String, String)>` for example:

```
var data: Array<(String, String)> = [("DEV", "DEV"), ("QUA", "QUA"), ("SIT", "SIT"), ("UAT", "UAT"), ("PROD", "PROD")]

for element in data {
    print(element.1)
}
//DEV
//QUA
//SIT
//UAT
//PROD
```

Comment: I want it to be a dictionary and get the values through enumerate()