# Sort Dictionary by value with tie Element should not change their order

Tags: swift, sorting, swift3, swift-dictionary

I have a Dictionary of type [String: Int] and its value is

```
let dic = [“a”:4, “b”:3, “c”:3]
```

I want to sort the dictionary by value and using method

```
dic  = dic.sorted(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
```

Result

```
dic = [“c”:3, “b”:3, “a”:4]
```

It is sorting the dictionary but i want the values which are same should not to be sort or change their order, for example, I want this result

```
dic = [“b”:3, “c”:3, “a”:4]
```

Comment: A dictionary is an *unordered* collection of key/value pairs. There is no sort order in a dictionary.

Comment: Why do you want to sort it in the first place?

Comment: Then what should I use to obtain the result?

Comment: these are the score of the players I put them in dic but I have to sort the player according to their score with above criteria

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090016/sort-dictionary-by-values-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that [dictionary is an unordered collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary), so trying to sort it is not the best thing to do.

If you want to store the score values for your game (for a leader-board i.e.) you can use [tuples](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID329).

```
typealias Score = (username: String, score: Int)
```

Then use can create an array of that tuples and sort them any way you want.

```
var scores = [Score]()

// fill the scores
scores.append(("a", 4))
scores.append(("b", 3))
scores.append(("c", 3))

scores.sort {
    return $0.score < $1.score || ($0.score == $1.score && $0.username.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.username) == .orderedAscending)
}
```

Comment: The solution worked for me thank you. You saved my life

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is unordered. This means that whatever order you see the KVPs in code is not guaranteed to be maintained. The `sort` call only says to sort by values, so the keys can be in whatever order they want.

Also note that Swift's `sorted(by:)` is not [stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important). This means things that are considered equal are not guaranteed to maintain their order.

Therefore, you can't really do anything about it if you insist on using Swift's built in algorithms. You could write an insertion sort (a stable sorting algorithm) yourself and use it though.

Another solution is to order the KVPs by values, then by keys:

```
let newDict = dict.sorted(by: { $0.value == $1.value ? $0.key < $1.key : $0.value < $1.value })
```

Obviously this will only work if your player names are ordered lexicographically originally.

Alternatively, create a `Player` struct and use an array of `Player`s:

```
struct Player {
    let name: String
    var score: Int
}
```