# Filter an array to sum of the another array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that many elements, but two of them are important to me. 
Language 
and number

I get the info from them someting like that

```
_ = cities[0].language 

\\give me a string languages(it could be any languages and maybe it's nil, but all the language are written in same way (for example it's always English, not english)
```

and

```
_ = cities[0].number 
\\give me an Int
```

for example it gives me something like that

> "English" "124324"
>
> "French" "5634"
>
> "English" "753"
>
> "German" "8643"
>
> "German" "532"
>
> nil "6532"

I want to create a new array(let's call `languageInfo`), that created by filtering the `cities` array.
I need it combine all the same lanugage together with sum of their numbers, for example the output should be something like that

for example it gives me something like that

> "English" "125077"
>
> "German" "9175"
>
> "French" "5634"
>
> "nil" "6532"

Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: What did you try so far that didn't work out? Can you post some code?

Comment: actually I don't know how to filter this kind of data the way that I want, I never do something like that before

Comment: I would take a look at the Array reduce function. Also, I would recommend using a Dictionary for your end result as I think that design fits better than an Array in your case. For example: `Dictionary<String?, Int>`. If you continue to struggle with that then please post an update with some code so that we can help you on your way. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reduce to sum the numbers and convert to a dictionary

As pointed out in the comments `reduce` can be written in a much more condensed form

```
let dict = cities.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.language ?? "", default: 0] += $1.number }
```

---

*Original version*

```
let dict = cities.reduce(into: [String: Int](), { result, city in
    var value = city.number
    let key = city.language ?? ""
    if let sum = result[key] {
        value += sum
    }
    result[key] = value
})
```

Note that I use an empty string as key if language is nil, another option could be to ignore those elements

```
let dict2 = cities.reduce(into: [String: Int](), { result, city in
    var value = city.number
    if let key = city.language {
        if let sum = result[key] {
            value += sum
        }
        result[key] = value
    }
})
```

or as pointed out in the comments allow `nil` as key

```
let dict = cities.reduce(into: [String?: Int](), { result, city in
    var value = city.number
    let key = city.language
    if let sum = result[key] {
        value += sum
    }
    result[key] = value
})
```

Comment: You can also just use `[String?:Int]` instead of `[String:Int]` for the dictionary type

Comment: @MichaelFourre Thanks, I am so used from java that key can not be nil.

Comment: I really really appreciate for your help.

Comment: dear @JoakimDanielson, just a question, how can I print the most used language now and its percentage?

Comment: @Robert That is a different question really but you can sort the dictionary like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50098633/9223839) (but use > instead of <) and get the first element in the result and to get the sum of all numbers you can use `reduce` but since this is already part of the solution you can add a new variable and add `value` to it in the current `reduce`. `if let max = sorted.first {
    print(max.key, 100.0 * Double(max.value)/total)
}`

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. No need to set the resulting type explicitly. Btw Swift 4 or later you can use Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value `cities.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.language, default: 0] +=  $1.number }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, I keep forgetting about `default` so I never got that version to work. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciated