# Swift 5 Dictionary sortedKeysByValue

Tags: swift

I need to get a sorted key list from a dictionary by their values.

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24090641/1282160) close to this question but not good enough:

```swift
extension Dictionary {
  func sortedKeysByValue(by compareMethod: (Value, Value) -> Bool) -> [Key] {
    return self
      .sorted {
        let (lk, lv) = $0
        let (rk, rv) = $1
        return compareMethod(lv, rv)
      }
      .map {
        let (key, _) = $0
        return key
      }
  }
}

let dict = ["a": 5, "b": 3, "c": 10, "d": 7, "e": 9, "f": 5]
let result = dict.keysSortedByValue(>)

// The result could be: 
// ["c", "e", "d", "a", "f", "b"] or 
// ["c", "e", "d", "f", "a", "b"]
```

The question is that: **when the value is equal, it should compare the keys to always produce the same results**. To do so, I need to make `compareMethod` not just accept `Value` type but also `Key` type. I try to make the method signature use `Comparable` protocol, but is gets a compilation error:

```swift
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable, Value: Comparable {
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ensure Key/Value types are Comparable
  func sortedKeysByValue(by compareMethod: (Comparable, Comparable) -> Bool) -> [Key] {
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^ got error (see below)
    return self
      .sorted {
        let (lk, lv) = $0
        let (rk, rv) = $1
        return compareMethod(lv, rv) || (lv == rv && compareMethod(lk, rk))
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ compare keys when values are equal 
      }
      .map {
        let (key, _) = $0
        return key
      }
  }
}
```

Compilation error: `Protocol 'Comparable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

The `compareMethod` should be able to handle both `Value` type and `Key` type. How do I fix it?

Comment: "I found an answer close to this question"  Que!?  What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The compareMethod should be able to handle both `Value` type and `Key` type.

It is not possible to declare such a function. You need one function to compare the keys, and another to compare the values.

You can write it like this:

```
// doesn't have to be Comparable, just conforming to Equatable is fine, as you are only using "=="
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
    func sortedKeysByValue(byComparingValues compareValues: (Value, Value) -> Bool, andComparingKeys compareKeys: (Key, Key) -> Bool) -> [Key] {
    return self
        .sorted {
            let (lk, lv) = $0
            let (rk, rv) = $1
            return compareValues(lv, rv) || (lv == rv && compareKeys(lk, rk))
        }.map(\.key)
    }
}
```

IMO, a better way to do this is to use `(Value, Value) -> ComparisonResult` functions, rather than `(Value, Value) -> Bool`. This not only allows the caller to specify their custom definition of equality, rather than always using "==", but also makes the method available on all types of dictionaries.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func sortedKeysByValue(byComparingValues compareValues: (Value, Value) -> ComparisonResult, andComparingKeys compareKeys: (Key, Key) -> Bool) -> [Key] {
        return self
            .sorted {
                let (lk, lv) = $0
                let (rk, rv) = $1
                switch compareValues(lv, rv) {
                case .orderedAscending:
                    return false
                case .orderedDescending:
                    return true
                default:
                    return compareKeys(lk, rk)
                }
            }.map(\.key)
    }

}
```

The downside is of course that you can't easily pass a comparison operator to this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `??` is typo; it should be `&&`. The one line code should be `compareMethod(lv, rv) || (lv == rv && compareMethod(lk, rk))`. I corrected the post.

Comment: @李岡諭 Ah that makes sense. I was confused why you thought `??` could be used there, haha.

Comment: Key already conforms to Hashable. There is no need to add a Equatable constrain.

Comment: @LeoDabus oh gosh silly me! My brain doesn’t work well at night :)