# Use '#selector' instead of explicitly constructing a 'Selector' warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this line in my code:

```
let argsort = (scores as NSDictionary?)?.keysSortedByValue(using: Selector("compare:"))
```

but XCode gives me a `Use '#selector' instead of explicitly constructing a 'Selector'` warning. However, the proposed fix:

```
let argsort = (scores as NSDictionary?)?.keysSortedByValue(using: #selector(NSTextLocation.compare(_:)))
```

requires iOS version 15.0, and therefore does not work for me (I am targetting iOS 13.0).

How can I either silence this warning or find a way out of this? Thanks

Comment: `let argsort = (scores as NSDictionary?)?.keysSortedByValue(using: #selector(compare(_:)))`. Simply drop the `NSTextLocation.`. And why all of the optionals?

Comment: BTW - Instead of using `NSDictionary`, use Swift code. See [Sort Dictionary by values in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090016/sort-dictionary-by-values-in-swift)

Comment: Cannot find 'compare' in scope

Comment: What kind of keys do you have in the dictionary? Change `NSTextLocation.` to whatever class your keys are (assuming it has a `compare:` method. But again, use the Swift solution instead.

Comment: Thanks NSTextLocation was actually the wrong type suggestion.. Should have checked. This is now solved